# Why different issues are found when using different versions of SonarQube?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I'm testing sonar in order to ensure the closing database connections and I'm having extrange results I don't understand.

I'm trying two versions of the code executing the maven goal "sonar:sonar" from eclipse with the embeded maven version 3.3.9.

I've tried with three versions of sonarqube server: 5.6.6, 6.2 and 6.4.

With this code

```
package db;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class TestClosingResources {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection con = null;
        ResultSet rsGet = null;
        PreparedStatement psGet = null;
        try {
            DriverManager.registerDriver (new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "test", "test");              

            psGet = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM TEST");
            rsGet = psGet.executeQuery();
            int counter = 0;
            while (rsGet.next()) {
                counter++;
                System.err.println(counter);
            } 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (rsGet != null) {
                    rsGet.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            rsGet = null;
            try {
                if (psGet != null) {
                    psGet.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            psGet = null;
        }
    }

}
```

I have these issues about closing resources:

sonarqube 5.6.6:

- Close this "Connection"
- Close this "PreparedStatement"

sonarqube 6.2:

- Close this "Connection"
- Close this "PreparedStatement"

sonarqube 6.4:

- Close this "Connection"

My question with this code is:

- **Why does 5.6.6 and 6.2 complain about PreparedStatement when it's
  closed exactly the same than the ResultSet?**

And whith this code (only changes the way I retrieve the connection, it doesn't matter if it would work or not)

```
package db;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class TestClosingResources {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection con = null;
        ResultSet rsGet = null;
        PreparedStatement psGet = null;
        try {
            InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
            DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/testci");
            con = ds.getConnection();       

            psGet = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM TEST");
            rsGet = psGet.executeQuery();
            int counter = 0;
            while (rsGet.next()) {
                counter++;
                System.err.println(counter);
            } 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (rsGet != null) {
                    rsGet.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            rsGet = null;
            try {
                if (psGet != null) {
                    psGet.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            psGet = null;
        }
    }

}
```

sonarqube 5.6.6:

- Close this "PreparedStatement"

sonarqube 6.2:

- Close this "PreparedStatement"

sonarqube 6.4:

- no issues about closing resources

My questions with this code are:

- **Why does 5.6.6 and 6.2 complain about PreparedStatement when it's
  closed exactly the same than the ResultSet?**
- **Why doesn't any version complain about not closing the connection?**

Thanks

Comment: What version of Java plugin do you use? Sonar versions can use different versions of the java plugin

Comment: The fact that 6.4 does not warn about the PreparedStatement indicates that some problem was fixed here.

Comment: I answered your question why you are seeing different results with different versions. I also suggested the change of a title to reflect this part. Please post another question about issue not being raised when `Connection` is retrieved from `DataSource`,  it is not directly related.

Comment: Hi,
I understand. Each version of sonarqube I was testing was using a different version of the java plugin. I'm sure that upgrading all to the same version will produce the same result.

I updated the 6.2 to the latest java plugin (4.10.0.10260) and I still don't get a issue for not closing the connection, so I'm going to open a new question as you suggested.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I've filled this new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44650648/why-sonarqube-doesnt-generate-an-issue-for-not-closed-connection

Answer (score 1):

The reason why some issues are not detected in more recent versions is due to the fact that static analyzer doing the analysis was improved.

Plugin used for Java source code analysis is called SonarJava, and it has independent release cycle than SonarQube. You should always use the latest release to obtain best results. Use update center on your SonarQube server to update to the latest available release.

Comment: Hi @Tibor I'll have a look. Thanks