# Why sonarqube doesn't generate an issue for not closed connection?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I'm testing sonar in order to ensure the closing database connections.

I'm executing the maven goal "sonar:sonar" from eclipse with the embeded maven version 3.3.9. with sonarqube 6.2 with sonar-java-plugin-4.10.0.10260.jar.

With this code

```
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class STestClosingResources extends HttpServlet{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public final void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        Connection con = null;
        ResultSet rsGet = null;
        PreparedStatement psGet = null;
        try {
            InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
            DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/testci");
            con = ds.getConnection();

            psGet = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM TEST");
            rsGet = psGet.executeQuery();
            int counter = 0;
            while (rsGet.next()) {
                counter++;
                System.err.println(counter);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (rsGet != null) {
                    rsGet.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            rsGet = null;
            try {
                if (psGet != null) {
                    psGet.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            psGet = null;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't get this issue I expected:

> Close this "Connection" in a "finally" clause.

Why?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

SonarJava analyzer responsible to analyze Java code and detect this issue doesn't recognize that `DataSource.getConnection` returns `Connection` which needs to be closed. I created ticket to fix it https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-2355

Comment: Ok, Thanks @Tibor

Comment: Hi @Tibor, I see that version 4.11 of the java plugin has been released. I've tested it and an issue is raised for not closing the connection with ds.getConnection(). Thank you very much for your help.